# tabbar controller inside navigation controller (storyboards!)

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I know that this question was discussed few times here, and in other websites, but posts are old (from 2009 or 2011) because of this they can't account changes in Apple environment.

So I started to build app firstly with navigation controller. In second view I need to switch to tab bar.
Now, I found posts that this is bad approach and the good one is to embed navigation controller **inside** tab bar not vice versa.
What is more my approach is working (segue from navigation controller to tab bar controller) and that posts are old. 
Is something changed in iOS 6.0?
Which approach is correct?

link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKPfO.png